# unique factorisation fails for cyclotomic integers $p>23$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, math-history

Background: I have stopped doing algebra a long time ago and I am not that interested in the nitty-gritty details of proofs, but I am interested in maths history.

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CyclotomicInteger.html claims unique factorisation fails for $p>23$

In Kummer's original work, let $\alpha$ be a $p$-th primitive root of unity. $f(\alpha)=a_0+a_1\alpha+\cdots+a_{p-1}\alpha^{p-1}$ and $Nf(\alpha) = f(\alpha)f(\alpha^2)\cdots f(\alpha^{p-1})$, where $N$ is his generalisation of norm from norm of Gaussian integers. This is always a rational integer for $f(\alpha)$.

Kummer defined $f(\alpha)|g(\alpha)$ if $Nf(\alpha)|Ng(\alpha)$

Here is my question:

For $p<23$, it seems cyclotomic integers just work like integers. There is a nice notion of divisibility and prime.
In the case $p=23$, using the notion of norm defined by Kummer, there is no factorisation for the number 47. It's norm is $47^{22}$ a not a prime integer, but there is no element in the 23rd-cyclotomic integer with norm 47, so this has no divisor. Is this related to the fact given in the link? 
(It seems not because the link says $p>23$ and this is a fact for $p=23$, but is there something fundamental I am missing?)

Comment: A quibble/typo: since $\alpha$ satisfies $\alpha^{p1}+\alpha^{p-2}+\ldots\alpha+1=0$, in your expression $f(\alpha)$ you do not need/want the $\alpha^{p-1}$ summand...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you correctly guess, unique factorization fails for $p = 23$.

In fact it fails in the ring
$\mathbb Z[(1 + \sqrt{-23})/2],$ which is a quadratic subring of the ring of cyclotomic integers for $p = 23$, and although it is not obvious, this 
implies that it fails in the cyclotomic integer ring.  Also, the reason that 
$47$ witnesses the failure is related to the fact that $47 \equiv 1 \bmod 23$.

Comment: so are you claiming wolfram mathworld erred? *gasp*

Comment: Dear Lost, I didn't follow the link, but I guess I am implicitly claiming this.   However, just as an independent verification, here is [another link](http://fermatslasttheorem.blogspot.com/2006/07/cyclotomic-integers-unique_25.html) that agrees with my answer. (I found it just by googling "failure of unique factorization in cyclotomic integers".)  I also vaguely remembered $23$ as being the key threshhold, and I know enough number theory that I could construct the argument behind my answer and assert it with reasonable confidence.  (But it's still nice that google backs me up!)  Cheers,

Comment: so it is a mistake on wolfram :), can't put your trust in anyone these days... dear oh dear... I guess next time, I will check more than 1 source.

Comment: @Lost1: Dear Lost, You probably know it, but Edwards's book on Kummer and Fermat's Last Theorem is a pretty good source, with (as far as I know) reliable history.  Also, any history by Andre Weil on Kummer is likely reliable.  (I think he edited Kummer's collected works, and likely wrote introductory material for them; certainly he was interested in Kummer both historically and mathematically.  I don't know if glancing in his collected works will show any expository/historical writing about Kummer.)   Regards,